# For an odd prime $p$, prove that the quadratic residues of $p$ are congruent modulo $p$ to the integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For an odd prime $p$, prove that the quadratic residues of $p$ are congruent modulo $p$  to the integers 
$$1^2,2^2, 3^2,\ldots, \left(\dfrac{p-1}{2}\right)^2$$

I know Euler's criterion but not sure how to start the proof. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quadratic residues modulo $p$ consists  of the numbers $1^2,2^2,\ldots ,(p-1)^2$ by definition. But these $p-1$ squares are pairwise congruent because of $x^2\equiv (x-p)^2 \bmod p$. So it suffices to take $1^2,2^2,\ldots ,\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)^2$.

Comment: Ahh so the first $(p-1)/2$ squares are congruent to the last $(p-1)/2$ squares... nice xD got it ! ty =)